# FABRICJS TEXT ( Resize bounding box )

Tags: fabricjs

I need a custom text box that you can resize the bounding box, WITHOUT stretching the font.

Created a custom fabric class based off of the fabric.Textbox class. Have some experience calling parent class methods within the custom class and overriding them.

```
    fabric['CustomText'] = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
      type: 'custom-text',
      initialize: function(element, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options)
        options && this.set('id', options.id) && this.set('clipTo', options.clipTo)
      },
      insertChars: function(chars) {
        if (this.maxWidth) {
          const textWidthUnderCursor = this._getLineWidth(this.ctx, this.get2DCursorLocation().lineIndex)
          if (textWidthUnderCursor + this.ctx.measureText(chars).width > this.maxWidth) {
            chars = '\n' + chars
          }
        }

        if (this.maxLines) {
          const newLinesLength = this._wrapText(this.ctx, this.text + chars).length
          if (newLinesLength > this.maxLines) {
            return
          }
        }

        // Call parent class method
        this.callSuper('insertChars', chars)
      },
      toObject: function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), { id: this.id, clipTo: this.clipTo })
      },
    })
```

I need to be able to

1. Stretch the TextBox's bounding box without the font changing scale.
2. Be able to drag in and drop text within the textbox at a particular character index.

Comment: You have an example here: http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink. Go to tab 'Simple' and you have 'Add textbox'

Comment: Thanks for that, but try stretching it down. It stretches the font. Additionally-- if you stretch diagonally, the font stretches. Fixed font size doesn't seem to do it. Maybe super the bounding box class?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the control visibility of the element to prevent vertical resizing. The textbox will adjust its height based on the content, but with the settings below you will still be able to control the width.

```
let textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 150,
  fontSize: 20
});

textbox.setControlsVisibility({
  tl: false,
  ml: true,
  bl: false,
  mb: false,
  br: false,
  mr: true,
  tr: false,
  mt: false
});
```